# Understanding the simplex form of the Euler Characteristic

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

I am having difficulty understanding how the simplex form of the Euler Characteristic (eq. 1 in [Toriwaki & Yonekura (2002)](http://www.scipress.org/journals/forma/pdf/1703/17030183.pdf))

$$\chi = n_{0} - n_{1} + n_{2} - n_{3}$$

where $n_{k}$ are the $k$-simplexes is derived from (or related to) the typical Euler Characteristic equation

$$\chi = v - e + f$$

where $(v,e,f)$ = (vertices, edges, faces).

How is this done?

Comment: $0$-simplices are points, $1$-simplices are edges, and $2$-simplices are faces.

Comment: yes, and what is the equivalent for the 3-simplices ($n_{3}$)?

Comment: Well, if you're talking about a polytope (which is the setting for the standard Euler characteristic), there aren't any because a polytope is only $2$-dimensional.

Comment: This is in the context of computing the Euler characteristic within the context of 3D digital images.  In this case, voxels are my vertices, a pair of face connected voxels make an edge, 4 voxels in a plane make a face and a 2x2x2 cube of voxels would make a 3-simplex.

Comment: Right, but $\chi=v-e+f$ is only for $2$-dimensional objects.

Comment: Ok.  So I'm a bit confused then about the usage of $\chi = v - e +f$. It is used in Baumgartner (1992) (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0378437192900774) for plaquettes embedded in 3-Dimensional Space, where the plaquettes are defined on surface of the voxels.  Was this not a valid thing for Baumgartner to do?

Comment: A surface is two-dimensional.  So, it's use is OK there.