# Interpretation of Fractional Genus

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

I have a graph with 8 nodes connected as a cube in 3 space (see diagram).  Using the simplex form of the Euler Characteristic (eq. 1 in [Toriwaki & Yonekura (2002)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eJGa.png))

$$\chi = n_{0} - n_{1} + n_{2} - n_{3}$$

where $n_{k}$ are the $k$-simplexes which are vertices (v), edges (e), faces (f) and cell (c)respectively.

In this graph I count :

$$ v = n_{0} =  8 $$
$$ e = n_{1} = 12 $$
$$ f = n_{2} = 6  $$
$$ c = n_{3} = 1 $$

Utilizing the relation,
$$\chi = 2 - 2g$$

and solving for the genus ($g$), I get $g = \frac{1}{2}$.  What is the interpretation of this genus value or where have I made a mistake?

**EDIT** : from the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2286566/understanding-the-simplex-form-of-the-euler-characteristic), this 2x2x2 cube would qualify for having a 3 simplex.  However, if I removed $n_{3}$, I would get the correct genus value.  I think this is the crux of my confusion.

**EDIT 2** : Based on the comments, instead be computing the genus, should I just be computing $\chi$ (which would = 1 using the simplex form of the Euler equation)?

[image: 8 nodes]

Comment: The genus formula is for closed surfaces. A solid cube is not a closed surface. Perhaps you want to look only at the boundary? In that case $n_3=0$ and $g=0$.

Comment: So does this definition of genus differ in context from the genus of a graph, e.g. the number of "handles" needed to avoid edge crossing?

Comment: The genus of a graph is the minimal genus of a surface you need in order to embed the graph. However, that cannot be calculated from Euler characteristic of the graph. (Also, a graph only has vertices and edges so its euler char is just V-E.)

Comment: I've seen usage of $\chi = v - e + f$ used for graphs, e.g. http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/GraphTheory/MyGraphTheory/planarity.htm.  Similar examples exist in Trudeau's book.  Are these incorrect usages of the Euler characteristic?

Comment: Graphs don't have faces. However, if you embed the graph in a surface, them v-e+f will compute the euler characteristic of that surface (not the graph), and the 2-2g formula will give you the genus of that surface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the solution is to follow the method outlined by [Chen and Rong (2010)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S016686411000115X).  They develop the theory for determining the genus in discretized (they call it 'digital') space.  Their solution is much easier to understand and implement (especially for non-mathematicians) in computer code than the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2299595/261088) given Brethlosze.

Basically for each volume element (i.e. voxel), identify the vertices located on the *surface* of the structure.  Don't consider vertices in the interior.  Then count the connectedness of each vertex.  Applying those rules to my above example, I have 8 vertices that are 3 connected.  Let's call this $M_{3} = 8$.

Equation 5 is :

$g = 1 + (|M_{5}| + 2\times|M_{6}| - |M_{3}|)/8$

In my above case, where my 8 nodes are the vertices of a single voxel:

$g = 1 + (0 + 2\times0 - 8)/8 = 1 - 8/8 = 0$

I've found this logic and equation to be very robust.

Answer (score 2):

This is the [Euler-Poincaré Characteristic](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~jaca2009/notes/Brasselet.pdf) formula, valid for complexes in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (or for topologies using the Betti Numbers), with $n_i$ the number of $\mathbb{R}^i$-simplexes:

$$
\chi=n_0-n_1+n_2-n_3+...
$$

For platonic solids in $\mathbb{R}^3$ this is equal to 2, and the sum is up to $n_2$.

The genus of an orientable $\mathbb{R}^3$ closed surface is:
$$
\chi=2-2g
$$

Note [this articiel](https://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/model/euler.html) for $\mathbb{R}^3$ surfaces, in which we realize that the previous formula turns into:

$$
\chi=L-F-2(S-G)
$$

Which is a remind for you about the $2$ and the $2g$ terms you naively are accepting.

You are seeking for the $\mathbb{R}^3$ genus, hence the sum is also up to $n_2$.

There is no 1/2 genus, unless you are having non orientable surfaces. This is a mistake here.

About genus of higher dimensions or topologies, or for accounting boundary components or non-orientable genus, that is another question.

Comment: "If you remove the said vertex" and which vertex is that?

Comment: I though you wanted to remove a vertex. For which i didnt have any reason. Omit that comment.